# Laravel vendor:publish not creating the file

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel "`php artisan vendor:publish`" not creating the config file from the package to be copied over to the main project if the file already exist. My problem is that I usually update some configs in my package and running the vendor:publish doesn't copy the file to the main app because I previously executed the command.

Comment: Please check folder permissions are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`php artisan vendor:publish --help` would show you the help information for the command. First option is

```
--force    Overwrite any existing files
```

So use

```
php artisan vendor:publish --force
```

to ... overwrite existing files.